# Generar controles por programacion C#

Tags: c#

Quiero generar textBox o listBox al precionar un buttom en un formulario seleccionado. (Del secundario al Principal). mediante Codigo ,Consiste en generar notas y agregarlas en un TabControl, que contiene un TabPage, en este deseo agregar los controles a generar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el Principal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este secundario

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace agenda
{
public partial class Nueva_asignatura : Form
{
    public Nueva_asignatura()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Nueva_asignatura_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "Guardar cambios";
    }

    private void checkBox6_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FmPrincipal Principal = new FmPrincipal();
        TabControl hoja = new TabControl();
        TabPage pagina = new TabPage();
        TextBox NuevaAsignatura = new TextBox();
        NuevaAsignatura.Location = new Point(400,150);
        pagina.Controls.Add(NuevaAsignatura);

        hoja.Controls.Add(pagina);
        //          NuevaAsignatura.Location = pagina.Controls.Add();
        // this.Controls.Add(NuevaAsignatura);

        NuevaAsignatura.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine
                              + textBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine
                              + textBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine
                              + domainUpDown1.Text + " : " + domainUpDown2.Text + Environment.NewLine
                              + domainUpDown3.Text + " : " + domainUpDown4.Text + Environment.NewLine.ToString();
        hoja.Location = new Point(300, 200);
       // Principal.Controls.Add(hoja);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo no te va a funcionar. De primeras, desde el formulario secundario creas un nuevo FmPrincipal, no va a hacer referencia al formulario principal que tenías ya creado.

Puedes crear la "hoja" en el segundo formulario y mandársela al principal creada ya o enviar los datos al principal y formarla ahí.

Para crearla en el secundario y pasarla al principal puedes hacer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace agenda
{
public partial class Nueva_asignatura : Form
{
    public delegate void pasoDatosHandler(TabControl h); //Declaramos un evento para enviarlo al otro formulario e indicamos que enviamos un TabControl
    public event pasoDatosHandler OnPasoDatos;
public Nueva_asignatura()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Nueva_asignatura_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Text = "Guardar cambios";
}

private void checkBox6_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FmPrincipal Principal = new FmPrincipal();
    TabControl hoja = new TabControl();
    TabPage pagina = new TabPage();
    TextBox NuevaAsignatura = new TextBox();
    NuevaAsignatura.Location = new Point(400,150);
    pagina.Controls.Add(NuevaAsignatura);

    hoja.Controls.Add(pagina);
    //          NuevaAsignatura.Location = pagina.Controls.Add();
    // this.Controls.Add(NuevaAsignatura);

    NuevaAsignatura.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine
                          + textBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine
                          + textBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine
                          + domainUpDown1.Text + " : " + domainUpDown2.Text + Environment.NewLine
                          + domainUpDown3.Text + " : " + domainUpDown4.Text + Environment.NewLine.ToString();
    hoja.Location = new Point(300, 200);

    if(OnPasoDatos != null) OnPasoDatos(hoja); //Enviamos la hoja al formulario principal
   // Principal.Controls.Add(hoja);
}
}
}
```

Ahora nos tenemos que suscribir a este evento desde el formulario principal donde, además de suscribirnos al evento, crearemos la función de callback para añadir la hoja al recibirla desde el formulario secundario. Este código es del formulario principal.

```
//Cuando creamos el formulario secundario nos suscribimos al evento que hemos creado
NuevaAsignatura formulario = new NuevaAsignatura();
formulario.OnPasoDatos += reciboDatos;

//Definimos la función reciboDatos que es donde recogeremos el TabControl enviado desde el formulario secundario y lo añadiremos al principal
public void reciboDatos(TabControl hoja)
{
    //Aquí ya tenemos el TabControl enviado desde el otro formulario.
    //Ya podemos agregar la hoja nueva que hemos creado
}
```

Otra opción que tienes, para hacerlo sin tocar tan apenas tu código, es pasar el formulario principal como parámetro a la hora de crear el formulario NuevaAsignatura, pero considero que es mejor respuesta la que te he escrito ya que el uso de eventos es muy importante y útil y pasar el formulario por el constructor lo considero una mala práctica.

Comment: De surgir mas dudas donde puedo consultarte?

Comment: si, no hay problema. Puede ser que, al intentar añadir la hoja te de un error que dice algo así como que no puedes modificar un control desde otro formulario pero no te preocupes, tiene fácil solución.

Comment: Oye , me marca un error.
 if(OnPasoDatos != null) OnPasoDatos(oPlaca);  OPlaca no esta declarado

Comment: Si, me he colado ahí al copiar el código, ahí lo que le pasas es hoja. Fíjate que al crear el delegado indicas que le pasas un TabControl, le tienes que pasar hoja, ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: Ya , pero me lo agrega en el formulario osea atras del tabControl, hay forma de mandarlo al frente? en el fondo naranja como el de la imagen.

Comment: Como lo añades con Controls.Add directamente? Si es así tienes que recorrer los controles hasta que te sitúes en el panel que lo quieras añadir y meterlo ahí

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69485/discussion-between-pablo-simon-diestefano-and-ricky1904).

Comment: Correcto, asi lo manejo. Podrias traducirlo a codigo? por que aun no entiendo bien este lenguaje.